# Setting the Open File dialog default view in Vista

Tags: windows-vista

In Windows Vista, it looks like everytime I navigate to a new directory a new "View type" is used. Sometimes it's a **list**, sometimes it's **detail**, etc.

I'd like to make it **detail** by default, but I can't seem to make it stick.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following article might help:

[Delete and Reset Windows Vista Folder Views or Folder Types Settings to Default Clean State](http://www.mydigitallife.info/2007/11/08/delete-and-reset-windows-vista-folder-views-or-folder-types-settings-to-default-clean-state/)

> Using Windows Explorer in Windows
>   Vista is sometimes annoying and
>   confusing as the folder views settings
>   and folder types customization is not
>   working consistently. Folder views
>   which determines which view, such as
>   tiles, details, list, small icons,
>   medium icons, large icons or extra
>   large icons, that users is using to
>   browse files and items in Explorer
>   window, while folder types set the
>   template which shows kind of folder
>   and its related commands and buttons
>   in toolbar. However, the
>   implementation in Vista is buggy,
>   messy and abnormal.
>
> The easiest solution all Folder Types
>   and Folder Views mess in Vista is by
>   reset all settings and customizations
>   related to Folder Types and Views to
>   revert back to out-of-the box
>   post-installation defaults. Note that
>   you should try to use Reset Folder in
>   Folder Options (open by clicking
>   Organize -> Folder and Search Options
>   and then go to View tab) before trying
>   registry hack below.
>
> Registry tweak below will delete and
>   reset all folder view and folder type
>   settings to default and clean state by
>   rebuilding the related registry key,
>   so that every start fresh again from
>   scratch. All remembered folder
>   settings in Windows Explorer for view
>   state, window position, sort order,
>   column information, folder type,
>   toolbar toggles, and search result
>   views will be lost, and reset to the
>   original defaults.

Answer (score 0):

a. Open Windows Explorer. Set the particulars to the view you prefer.

b. Go to Tools and select “Folder Options”;

c. Click on the “View” tab;

d. Click on the “Apply to All Folders” button;

e. You will be prompted a message: “Set all the folders on your computer to match the current folder’s view settings (except for toolbars and folder tasks)? Changes will occur the next time you open them”. Click “Yes”;

f. Click “OK” to complete

Comment: That doesn't seem to work for the open file dialog, only for windows opened by explorer itself. :(

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to do this, I assume you can achieve this by editing some keys in the registry